# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'revision_uid'

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I updated D-8.3.9 to D-8.7.1 and while updating db `drush updb` I am getting

```
Performing paragraphs_update_8016
Failed: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'revision_uid' in 'where clause': SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM
{paragraphs_item_field_data} t
WHERE revision_uid IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0; Array()
```

Any help is appreciated